# gcc 4.3.4 bug with structure size?

Tags: gcc, struct

What's wrong with this code when I compile it with -DPORTABLE?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    unsigned char data[11];

#ifdef PORTABLE
    unsigned long intv;
#else
    unsigned char intv[4];
#endif

} struct1;

int main() {

    struct1 s;

    fprintf(stderr,"sizeof(s.data) = %d\n",sizeof(s.data));
    fprintf(stderr,"sizeof(s.intv) = %d\n",sizeof(s.intv));
    fprintf(stderr,"sizeof(s) =      %d\n",sizeof(s));

    return 0;
}
```

The output I get on 32 bit GCC:

```
$ gcc -o struct struct.c -DPORTABLE
$ ./struct 
sizeof(s.data) = 11
sizeof(s.intv) = 4
sizeof(s) =      16
$ gcc -o struct struct.c 
$ ./struct 
sizeof(s.data) = 11
sizeof(s.intv) = 4
sizeof(s) =      15
```

Where did the extra byte came from?

I always thought 11+4 = 15 not 16.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing's wrong with the code; those sizes are correct. The compiler may add padding to `struct`s at its discretion. The size of a `struct` is only guaranteed to be large enough to hold its elements, so adding the sizes of its elements is not a reliable way to get the size of the `struct`.

Such padding can be helpful in keeping elements and the structs themselves aligned to specific boundaries, both to avoid alignment errors (perhaps why it's enabled with `-DPORTABLE`) and as  a speed optimization, as Als points out.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to **[structure padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment#Data_structure_padding)**.
Compilers are free to add extra padding bytes to structures to optimize the access time.

This is the reason You should always use **[sizeof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment#Data_structure_padding)** operator and never manually calculate  size of structures.

Answer (score 1):

It's called alignment. That's especially added padding at end of structures to decrease cache misses. If you want to disable it, you can use something like that:

```
#pragma pack(push)  /* push current alignment to stack */
#pragma pack(1)     /* set alignment to 1 byte boundary */

typedef struct {
  unsigned char data[11];

#ifdef PORTABLE
  unsigned long intv;
#else
  unsigned char intv[4];
#endif
} struct1;

#pragma pack(pop)   /* restore original alignment from stack */
```